# Use css in simple_html_dom php?

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I have source code :

```
<li class="parent">
<a href="#">F</a>
<ul>
    <li>xx</li>
    <li>xx</li>
     ......
</ul>
</li>
```

I want get `plaintext` of tag `li:nth-child(1)` by simple_html_dom :

```
$html->find("li.parent li:nth-child(1)")
```

not

```
$html->find("li.parent li",0);
```

Comment: to find the text of the `a` tag you have to use this line of code `$html->find("li.parent a")`

Comment: Oh, sorry... :D i want find `li:nth-child(1)`

Comment: I still don't know what is your problem/question.

Comment: @LuthandoLoot if you have only one `a` tag else you must loop over the result ;)

Comment: @Maraboc yes you are right

Comment: I'm doing crawler, retrieve data like jquery. but that does not seem to support simple_html_dom `selector` as css

Comment: what is the expected result of this `$html->find("li.parent li:nth-child(1)")` ???

Comment: @Maraboc : I have recently written wrong : I want get plaintext of tag `a` by simple_html_dom. And Post has been edited . LOL!

Comment: try this `strip_tags($html->find("li.parent li:nth-child(1)")->innertext);` :)

Comment: it not working ! 
 
I have file config. My code read this file. In file have `structure selector` css. I want change them in file config, not edit my code. Ex: `$html->find("li.parent li",0...n)` by `$html->find("li.parent li:nth-child(1...n)")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use complicated css with simple html dom.
I suggest switching to [this one](http://sourceforge.net/projects/advancedhtmldom/?source=directory):

```
$html = <<<EOF
<li class="parent">
<a href="#">F</a>
<ul>
    <li>xxx</li>
    <li>yyy</li>
</ul>
</li>
EOF;

require_once('advanced_html_dom.php');
$doc = str_get_html($html);
echo $doc->find("li.parent li:nth-child(2)", 0)->text;
// yyy
```

Comment: It not work :( `Catchable fatal error: Argument 2 passed to DOMXPath::query() must be an instance of DOMNode, null given, called in D:\Work\PHP\xampp\htdocs\crawler\includes\base\advanced_html_dom.php on line 89 and defined in D:\Work\PHP\xampp\htdocs\crawler\includes\base\advanced_html_dom.php on line 50 `

Comment: That means it's not there. See my edit, this works fine as is.

Answer (score 0):

To find only the first child of the `ul` you can use:

```
$html->find("li.parent li:nth-child(1)")
```

OR

```
$html->find("li.parent li:first-child")
```

But to get all the `li`'s you have to use a loop like this:

```
 foreach($html->find("li.parent li") as $element) 
   echo $element->plaintext. '<br>';
```

Comment: If i want get `li.parent li:nth-child(2,3...4...n)` ? Because i have file config. My code read this file. In file have `structure selector` css. I want change them in file config, not edit my code. Ex: `$html->find("li.parent li",0...n)` by `$html->find("li.parent li:nth-child(1...n)")`

Comment: you can use the first option to get `li` in any position you want, e.g if you want the second `li` you can get it this way `$html->find("li.parent li:nth-child(2)")`

Comment: Thanks ! It seems it does not working. I have a multi-level menu, I want to take just under the menu tag `a` in the parent menu , and not get `a` in the submenu. e.g : `$html->find("li.parent > a")` .. But it get all tag `a` in parent menu and submenu .. LOL !

Comment: i dont understand what you're saying, if you want the sub `li`'s text you cannot use `a` tag in your selector because those `li`'s are not under the `a` tag

Comment: try this `foreach($html->find("li.parent > a > ul > li:nth-child(1) > a")) `
    `echo $element->href. '<br>'; `

Comment: U can test url : `news.zing.vn`. I try .. but it not working :( hi.

Comment: `foreach($html->find("nav.categories li.parent::nth-child(2) > a") as $e) print $e->plaintext;` .. it get all text of all menu.

Comment: i want get only text of parent menu in [IMAGE](http://i.stack.imgur.com/cRc46.png)  @@

Comment: lets do this one more time, try this `foreach($html->find("#top > nav > ul > li.parent.xa-hoi > div > ul > li:nth-child(1) > a") as $e) print $e->plaintext;`

Comment: sorry but it return NULL :3 Hi hi .. 

[RETURN IMAGE](http://i.imgur.com/x349JGC.png)

Comment: replace `print $e->plaintext;` with `print $e->href;`

Comment: @@ it not find tag `a` .. Thanks you. I try it.